# Swift NSTimer Coding

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer, swift2

Using Swift 2.0 and trying to implement Swift NSTimer in Custom Keyboard. Button2 shows up great when Button1 is pressed, until the NSTimer kicks in and crashes the keyboard.

I'm trying to hide Button2 after a few seconds.

```
@IBAction func Button1(sender: UIButton) {
    Button2.setTitle("Text", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("Hide:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    Button2.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Could we also see what `Hide()` looks like? Maybe something is going wrong there.

Comment: Show your `Hide:` function definition.

Comment: @Cole func Hide(){
    Button2.hidden = true
        }

Comment: add `@objc` in front of `func Hide()....`  + your func should take one argument you specified

Comment: It's giving me the error message 'Only classes, protocols, methods, initializers, properties, and subscript declarations can be declared @objc.

Comment: Check one more time, func is a method is within a class. It should work, I have in front of me this type of declaration that works.

Comment: Still no luck. If it makes a difference, I'm using XCode Beta 7 (Swift 2.0), but it shouldn't I don't think.

Comment: @Caitlin So it looks like you want the button to appear, and disappear after 1 second. At least I believe your logic to work that way. Maybe it's a problem with the sequence of execution. Try moving `Button2.hidden = false` to the line before the `NSTimer` declaration.

Comment: @ Caitlin Also if `Hide()` does not accept any parameters, change `"Hide:"` to `"Hide"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (note that I changed some of the function names to more closely follow conventions):

```
@IBAction func button1Tapped() {
    button2.setTitle("Text", forState: .Normal)
    button2.hidden = false
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "hideButton2", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func hideButton2() {
    button2.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: @Caitlin I also recommended this, and you said that does not work (

Answer (score -2):

Replace `Selector("Hide:")` with `"Hide:"` and add `@objc` in front of your func

Comment: That would not make *any* difference.

Comment: In Swift, `"foo:"` was built to operate the same as `Selector("foo:")`